# Curl Empty reply from server with code 100

Tags: curl

I have written a curl request on one server to fetch files from another server.
but it is giving Empty Response from server with 100 HTTP code.

Can somebody tell me what can be the issue?
My curl request calls one function which has below code.

```
        $file_name = $FileName_goes_here;
        $ext = pathinfo($docNameOnOtherServer, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $file_path = public_path()."/documents/".$folderName;
        $document_link_for_DB = $file_name .".".$ext;
        $sorceFilePath = "/var/www/appFolder/web/Docs/".$folderName."/".$docNameOnOtherServer;
      // when am checking file exist then it is going fail here only
        $fileExists = file_exists('ssh2.sftp://'.$sftp.$sorceFilePath );

        return $fileExists . " is response"; 

        if($fileExists){
            return " am after file exists ";
        $FileCopied = ssh2_scp_recv($connection,$sorceFilePath, $file_path."/".$file_name.".".$ext);

        }
```

when file exists, i have copy that file from another server to this server in folder.
Can somebody tell me where am wrong here.
[I have changed variable names while posting here.]

Answer (score 0):

You can try in your curl configuration, to establish

```
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 400);
```